# Будет ли создан один и тот же столбец если использовать @Column(nullable = false) или @NotNull?

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

У меня есть сущность с полем. Если я использую аннотацию `@Column(nullable = false)`, то у меня в бд будет столбец `not null`. Будет такой же столбец если я использую аннотацию `@NotNull` вместо `@Column`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Column(nullable = false)` это указание на атрибут столбца таблицы в БД. `@NotNull` - валидация, которая выполняется непосредственно в приложении **перед** вставкой в базу.
Валидация при помощи `@NotNull`, таким образом, не обязательна. Если имеется в виду автогенерация таблиц на основе аннотация, то `@NotNull` тут участвовать, в моём понимании, не будет.

[См. Confusion: @NotNull vs @Column(nullable = false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false)

Comment: Да, вы правы: 
>Как можно было видеть в главе 3, Bean Validation определяет ограничения только в рамках пространства Java. Поэтому @NotNull обеспечивает считывание фрагмента Java-кода,
который убеждается в том, что значением атрибута не является null. С другой стороны,
аннотация JPA @Column(nullable = false) используется в пространстве базы данных для
генерирования схемы базы данных. Аннотации JPA и Bean Validation могут сосуществовать в случае с тем или иным атрибутом.